# implementing "update if exists" in Doctrine ORM

Tags: php, sql, orm, doctrine

I am trying to `INSERT OR UPDATE IF EXISTS` in one transaction.

in **mysql**, I would generally use `DUPLICATE KEY` ("UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY".)  I'm aware of many solutions to this problem using various SQL variants and sub-queries, but I'm trying to implement this in Doctrine (PHP ORM).  It seems there would be Doctrine methods for doing this since it's so feature packed, but I'm not finding anything.  Is this sort of thing a problem using PHP ORM packages for some reason?  Or do any Doctrine experts know how to achieve this through hacks or any means?

Comment: I've started work on a plugin to implement this functionality. It's still in the early stages but tested and working for my use-case. It's available at: https://github.com/m14t/m14tDoctrineRecordPlugin Test cases, bug reports and pull requests welcome.

Comment: I think you should mark @pix0r 's answer as the solution

Comment: For anyone that finds this, merge() is deprecated and will be removed. https://github.com/doctrine/orm/pull/1577

Answer (score 7):

According to https://www.vivait.co.uk/labs/updating-entities-when-an-insert-has-a-duplicate-key-in-doctrine this can be achieved with `$entityManager->merge()`.

```
$entity = new Table();
$entity->setId(1);
$entity->setValue('TEST');

$entityManager->merge($entity);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: strange, but don't worked for me. i'm used https://stackoverflow.com/a/24384768/5809937  in symfony 3

Answer (score 6):

The only thing I can think of is to query first for the entity if it exists otherwise create new entity.

```
if(!$entity = Doctrine::getTable('Foo')->find(/*[insert id]*/))
{
   $entity = new Foo();
}
/*do logic here*/
$entity->save();
```

Comment: There's nothing that ensures that the row isn't created between the query and the save.

Comment: Isn't that what transactions are for?

Comment: Very dangerous, like @IliaJerebtsov said, a row can be created between the persist and the flush. In this case you should consider to use pure SQL ;-(

Answer (score 3):

Doctrine supports `REPLACE INTO` using the `replace()` method.  This should work exactly like the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` you were looking for.

Docs: [Replacing Records](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/component-overview.html#replacing-records)

Comment: the only problem with REPLACE seems to be that it drops and then creates a new row (rather than performing an actual UPDATE), thus dropping the auto increment ids (in this case, my primary id). Am I missing something here?
eg - my auto increment id is 9, but the count is as 3000.  When I perform REPLACE INTO for row 9, the new row id is 3001.

Comment: Its not a solution, the replace seems make a delete/insert and change autonumeric values (ex id)

Comment: `REPLACE INTO` is not equivalent to `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`. The 1st will delete the row and insert a new one. If there are delete triggers or foreign keys (even more with `CASCADE`), `REPLACE` is not a viable option.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an option anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is to call entityManager->merge($entity);
Because it's the closest thing to update if exist operation as promised in documentation: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-objects.html