# Find or create (upsert) functionality in Doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine, doctrine-orm

Does Doctrine 2 have upsert functionality built in? It doesn't seem to, but I wasn't able to find a definitive yes-or-no answer.

If it does, I would of course be interested to see an example and/or some documentation.

Comment: This seems like a duplicate question.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132571/1644036

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I found the answer. As of today (10/15/2012), there's an open "[add upsert support](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/5178)" issue for Doctrine. I assume that this ticket wouldn't still be open if Doctrine 2 did have upsert support, so I guess there's my definitive answer.

Comment: I can see there's a ticket, but couldn't find any documentation? Did you?

Answer (score 2):

Upsert is already present in Doctrine.

Using the query builder, you have to set **findAndUpdate()** and **returnNew()** if you want to return the document. Set **upsert()** and you're ready to go.

For example:

```
$documentMannager->createQueryBuilder('App\Domain')
->findAndUpdate()
->returnNew()
->field('_id')->equals($id)
->field('page')->equals($page)
->field('count')->inc(1)
->upsert()
->getQuery()
->execute();
```

This is the way i implement a bucket pattern.

Comment: Thank you @Guilherme I will test this approach and will come back to you with my results!

Comment: Only applies to ODM and not ORM.

Comment: As @Im0rtality says, it only could be used in the context of Mongo, and not of SQL databases.