# Doctrine 2 update or insert

Tags: doctrine-orm

i'm making a counter of tags for the content of my site.

I'm saving the total amount of tags in one table, saving the content_id, tagType_id and the total.

doctrine can update an existent entity or create new one by own? Or I must check it with a select?

Comment: What do you mean by the total?

Comment: No, doctrine2 has no [general *upsert* functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12898697/find-or-create-upsert-functionality-in-doctrine-2). You need to check and update/insert yourself.

Comment: @StephanVierkant total is a the amount of total tags :)

Comment: Why don't you use count()?

Comment: I wont to use Count in SQL, is so slow