# How to do an "if exists update else insert" in doctrine?

Tags: sql, doctrine, request, symfony-1.4

I would like to do this request in Doctrine :

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Column1='SomeValue')
        UPDATE Table1 SET (...) WHERE Column1='SomeValue'
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO Table1 VALUES (...)
```

The only way is to do a `replace into` from what I read ([Doctrine docs](http://doctrine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/en/manual/component-overview.html#replacing-records)) but the problem with `REPLACE` seems to be that it drops and then creates a new row (rather than performing an actual `UPDATE`)...

Comment: Did you check this question: [implementing "update if exists" in Doctrine ORM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132571/implementing-update-if-exists-in-doctrine-orm) ?

Comment: @j0k Yes I check it, but there is no really solution..

Comment: Have you looked at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132571/implementing-update-if-exists-in-doctrine-orm a comment mentions this plugin: https://github.com/m14t/m14tDoctrineRecordPlugin

Comment: @MarcelloRomani I work on a professional project, I can't use unofficial plugin.